# Hola, ví esta porción de codigo en un problema, solo habia que resolver la funcion en la parte de '_,*res,_'

Tags: python-3.x

**Let's call a list beautiful if its first element is equal to its last element, or if a list is empty. Given a list a, your task is to chop off its first and its last element until it becomes beautiful. Implement a function that will make the given a beautiful as described, and return the resulting list as an answer.(Solo tengo que implementar una porcion de codigo el resto no importa, solo quiero sabre para que se usa *,*res,*)**

```
def solution(a):
res = a[:]
while res and res[0] != res[-1]:
  _, *res, _ = res
return res
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Aunque el enunciado está en inglés, el idioma oficial del sitio es el español. Traduce la pregunta por favor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La operación

```
_, *res, _ = res
```

es una forma interesante, un poco retorcida, de eliminar el primer y último caracter.

Supongamos que tienes una lista `res = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. Cuando haces

```
a, b = res
```

Python intentara *desempaquetar* la lista en sus elementos individuales y asignarlos a las variables de la izquierda.

La variable `res` es una lista que desempaquetada produce cinco valores, y en la izquierda sólo tienes dos variables. Si intentas ejecutarla la instrucción se produce el error

```
    a,b = res
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

pues no calza el número de valores con el número de variables.

Para salvar la situación se pone un asterisco delante de una de las variables (es una *starred expression*) para indicar que esa variable recolectara todos los valores *huérfanos* en la asignación:

```
res = [1,2,3,4,5]
a, *b = res
print(a)    # => 1
print(b)    # => [2, 3, 4, 5]
```

También puedes combinar otras variables y Python distribuirá los valores para llenarlas todas

```
res = [1,2,3,4,5]
a, *b, c = res       
print(a)    # => 1
print(b)    # => [2, 3, 4]
print(c)    # => 5
```

Finalmente, sólo puedes usar una vez el asterisco en las variables del lado izquierdo.

**Solución pitónica**

Este código hace lo mismo pero de modo más tradicional (y probablemente más rápido)

```
def solution(a):
    while a and a[0] != a[-1]:
        a = a[1:-1]
    return a
```